# Fulcrum RT-013 fixing "Screw"

Tags: hub

I've sourced a 2010'ish Cube Agree GTC with very little use on Easton wheels.

Long story..... but I wanted to replace the noisy freehub and have sourced a new Fulcrum RT-013 unit. However I've lost the screw that locks it in place - its an externally threaded hollow "screw" that fits in from the non drive side and nips the static part of the freehub into a "splined" recess, machined into the alloy wheel hub ( driven by a large hex / allen key)

Ive searched various websites / exploded drawigns and cant find it so am struggling to source a replacement - either new or used

Pity as the wheels are otherwise in excellent condition and I've just spent £40 on a new freehub!

Does anyone have a part number for this item or any suggestion of how to source ....

Comment: It’s likely a grub/set screw, judging by your description. Take it to the hardware store and see what size set screw screws in. It’s almost certainly a metric size.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply but I'm fairly sure this is not a standard fixing - for a start it is hollow (to allow the axle to fit through).It is also finer threaded than standard metric threading for its diameter and has a larger diameter, circular (not hexagonal) shoulder "above" the threads to bear down on a corresponding reduced diameter machined into the hub body. In effect this is a hollow "bolt" that screws into the "nut" which is the female threaded free-hub body.

Comment: Ah makes sense. At first I thought you were just missing a little set screw or something. Try contacting the hub manufacturer for info?